# Is XAML a must for learning iOS programming?

Tags: ios, xaml, xamarin

I am new to iOS programming, looking to know if I need to learn XAML first before learning actual iOS programming?

Comment: No, unless you are using xamarin maybe

Comment: There is no need to learn XAML if you are starting native iOS development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I agree that XAML is not mandatory to learn iOS programming but if you are going to use Xamarin development (with Xamarin Forms), may be just a quick overview of XAML would be helpful. But in no way its a pre-requistie as you can achieve everything as drop-down of tools and writing code-behind code.

Answer (score 6):

No.  XAML is used in Xamarin Forms, and it is entirely optional.  If you are doing Xamarin iOS or Xamarin Android development (without using Forms) you do not use XAML at all.

If you are learning iOS development in Objective C or Swift XAML does not apply either.